# sold_amount and bought_amount return 0.0000 in /effects

Tags: manageofferoperation, dex, trade, effects

After placing `ManageOfferOperation`, when we call `/effects` endpoint we are getting `0.0000` in `sold_amount` and `bought_amount`.

Is this an issue of Stellar Core?

Answer (score 1):

If the trade amount is less than a rounding error (in other words, traded amount is smaller than 0.0000001), DEX engine treats it as a "dust" trade and closes the offer returning all buying/selling liabilities back to the account balance. It results in trade effects with zero traded amount.

Comment: okay...noted.But in same /effects api  there are four json object. First two json objects  bought_amount is showing 0.0000000  and in rest two json objects bought_amount is showing  more than the  total amount. In my case total amount is 132 but in /effects api bought_amount is showing 2024.